# Constrain panning on Openlayers map

Tags: openlayers-3, panning

Restricting the panning on an Openlayers map doesn’t have in mind the rotation. So when rotating the map, the constrain doesn't get rotated.

This two squares show the actual extent and the desired one:

[image]

I defined the constrain with "extent" option in view like that:

```
var baseView = new ol.View({
    center: [241160, 5069100],
    zoom: 11,
    extent: [226838, 5084100, 255700, 5055200]
});
```

Here is working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/fvgdqser/2/) for testing this behaviour.

How can I implement to constrain panning having rotation in mind?

Comment: Your JSFiddle seems to demonstrate that rotating the map *does* rotate the constrained area, i.e. the corners of the area are in the same geographical points no matter what the rotation is on the screen. Not sure why you'd expect any other behaviour?

Comment: You are right, the constrained area has the same rotation as the view. The problem is that I need to limit panning to an area which corresponds to the angle the user is seeing the map, like the second (horizontal) square I draw on the map. I thought that would be the standard behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, if you set maxExtent in your OSM layer, wouldn't it be restricted to that area? is that what you want?

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        extent: maxExtent
    })
```

Comment: Defining maxExtent in the layer only limits rendering ("The layer will not be rendered outside of this extent.") - but I want to limit the panning on the map.

Comment: Does 'map.setOptions({restrictedExtent: maxExtent});' suit you?

Comment: This was right for OL2, in OL3 it's done with option "extent" in the view. But the problem is that the extent doesn't respect the rotation as you can see in the linked jsfiddle.